# How to execute a stored procedure with cursor and table OUT parameters through SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I’m having trouble testing, in SQL Developer 3.2.20.09, an Oracle stored procedure that contains 2 specificities:

- a user defined "cursor type" output parameter
- a user defined "TABLE OF VARCHAR type" output parameter.

Stored procedure signature:

```
TYPE ref_cursor_tst IS REF CURSOR;
TYPE arrWarningCode_tst IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (4000)
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE SP_ITF_CU_DOCUMENT_Test (
p_projectNumber IN VARCHAR2,
p_tag IN VARCHAR2,
p_title IN VARCHAR2,
out_document_curs OUT ref_cursor_tst,
out_errorCode OUT VARCHAR2,
out_arrWarningCode OUT arrWarningCode_tst);
```

My actual best test code I could end up with:

```
set serveroutput on size 100000

DECLARE
     docRef               VARCHAR2(200);
     outDocCurs           PD360BADMIN.PKG_ITF_GENERAL_TST.ref_cursor_tst;
     outErrorCode         VARCHAR2(2000);
     arrWarningCodes      PD360BADMIN.PKG_ITF_GENERAL_TST.arrWarningCode_tst;
     i                    PLS_INTEGER;
     doc                  TBL_OBJECT%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('debut de procedure');

     docRef:= 'DOC-012';
     arrWarningCodes.DELETE;

     --call SP
     PKG_ITF_GENERAL_TST.SP_ITF_CU_DOCUMENT_TEST (
      p_projectNumber    => 'XXX', 
      p_tag              => docRef, 
      p_title            => 'Doc title', 
      out_document_curs  => outDocCurs, 
      out_errorCode      => outErrorCode,
      out_arrWarningCode => arrWarningCodes);

     --print error code 
     dbms_output.put_line('out_errorCode=' || outErrorCode);

     --print output cursor
     --dbms_output.put_line(outDocCurs);
     LOOP
       FETCH outDocCurs INTO doc;
       EXIT WHEN outDocCurs%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(doc.OBJ_ID||','||doc.OBJ_TAG);
     END LOOP;

     --print warnings array     
     IF  arrWarningCodes.count > 0 THEN
          FOR i IN arrWarningCodes.FIRST .. arrWarningCodes.LAST LOOP
                dbms_output.put_line('warning code=' || arrWarningCodes(i) );
          END LOOP; 
     ENd IF;

     dbms_output.put_line('fin de procedure');
END;
/
```

The error I get:

```
Error report:
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at line 30
06504. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"
*Cause:    Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared
           return type of a result set  variable, or declared types of two Result
           Set variables do not match.
*Action:   Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable
           actually refers to during execution.
debut de procedure
out_errorCode=
```

I've been testing various solutions and syntaxes for days as well as digging the net and requiring help from different sources with no success.

Any clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `TBL_OBJECT` a table of an object type, as the name suggests? Can you show the definition for the object and the table? What is the query that's used in the procedure to set `out_document_curs` - is that querying the same table, as a simple `select *`? And if so can you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TBL_OBJECT` is a table of some object type which has the two fields `obj_id` and `obj_tag`; and the procedure is currently doing something like:

```
open out_document_curs for select * from tbl_object;
```

... then there are two ways to make this work. The first is to change the variables you're fetching into to match the object fields, rather than the object itself:

```
DECLARE
     ...
     -- doc                  TBL_OBJECT%ROWTYPE;
     doc_obj_id           TBL_OBJECT.OBJ_ID%TYPE;
     doc_obj_tag          TBL_OBJECT.OBJ_TAG%TYPE;
BEGIN
    ...
```

and then change the fetch and display:

```
     LOOP
       FETCH outDocCurs INTO doc_obj_id, doc_obj_tag;
       EXIT WHEN outDocCurs%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(doc_obj_id||','||doc_obj_tag);
     END LOOP;
```

If the object has more fields then you'd need to define them all and specify them in the fetch too.

The other is to modify the procedure so that it returns an object type:

```
open out_document_curs for select value(t) from tbl_object t;
```

Then your calling anonymous block will work as it is, as the simple query will return the object itself rather than the fields within it.

Which you do will depend on how the procedure will really be used, rather than your test call.

With some dummy set-up:

```
create type doc_obj as object (obj_id number, obj_tag varchar2(10));
/
create table tbl_object of doc_obj;
insert into tbl_object values (doc_obj(1, 'Test'));
```

And a dummy package body with the procedure simplified as:

```
PROCEDURE SP_ITF_CU_DOCUMENT_Test (
p_projectNumber IN VARCHAR2,
p_tag IN VARCHAR2,
p_title IN VARCHAR2,
out_document_curs OUT ref_cursor_tst,
out_errorCode OUT VARCHAR2,
out_arrWarningCode OUT arrWarningCode_tst)
IS
BEGIN
    open out_document_curs for select value(o) from tbl_object o;
    out_errorCode := 'OK';
    out_arrWarningCode(1) := 'Danger!';
END SP_ITF_CU_DOCUMENT_Test;
```

Then calling your code exactly as you have it in the question (minus the schema name) gives:

```
anonymous block completed
debut de procedure
out_errorCode=OK
1,Test
warning code=Danger!
fin de procedure
```

Using the other approach, with the individual variables for the object fields, gives the same result too.